Is there any bug related to onClick function not being recognizedin React?
I'm working on a project with NextJs and TypeScript and I'm getting weird behaviours with onClick function. It seems it's not being recognized inside my component.
"use client";
import styles from "./UploadCard.module.css";
import Image from "next/image";
import Card from "@/components/Card/Card";
import { FaCloudUploadAlt, FaFileUpload } from "react-icons/fa";
import { SiMicrosoftexcel } from "react-icons/si";
import { ChangeEvent, FormEvent, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useUploadContext } from "@/contexts/uploadContext";
import { useUserContext } from "@/contexts/userContext";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import { MdOutlineClose } from "react-icons/md";
import { useToastContext } from "@/contexts/toastContext";

import { IoIosArrowBack, IoIosArrowForward } from "react-icons/io";
import SelectAddress from "./SelectAddress";
import Carousel from "./Carousel";
import CarouselSlide from "./CarouselSlide";
import { BASE_IMAGE_PATH } from "@/utils/constants";
import uploadService from "@/services/uploadService";
import { SavedAddress } from "@/services/userService";
import useFetch from "@/hooks/useFetch";
import SpreadSheetOptions from "./SpreadSheetOptions";
import checkIfDuplicated from "@/utils/checkIfDuplicated";
import { isError } from "@/utils/error";
import { isAxiosError } from "axios";

// The use cannot send more than FILE_LIMIT files
const KYLOBYTE = 1000;
const MEGABYTE = KYLOBYTE \* 1000;
const FILE_SIZE_LIMIT = 5 \* MEGABYTE;

function formatFileSize(size: number): string {
if (size \< KYLOBYTE) {
return `${size} B`;
} else if (size \>= KYLOBYTE && size \< MEGABYTE) {
return `${size / KYLOBYTE} KB`;
} else {
return `${size / MEGABYTE} MB`;
}
}

export interface FormData {
street: string;
number: string;
city: string;
state: string;
neighborhood?: string;
zipCode?: string;
}

function UploadCard() {
const \[file, setFile\] = useState\<File | null\>(null);
const \[roundTrip, setCyclicalRoute\] = useState\<boolean\>(false);
const { user } = useUserContext();
const { errorToast, promiseToast } = useToastContext();
const { isUploading } = useUploadContext();
const \[activeItem, setActiveItem\] = useState(0);
const \[headers, setHeaders\] = useState\<string\[\]\>(\[\]);
const { fetchExcelData } = useFetch();
const \[showDropdown, setShowDropdown\] = useState(false);
const \[activeInput, setActiveInput\] = useState("");
const \[selectedAddress, setSelectedAddress\] = useState\<SavedAddress | null\>(
null
);
const \[formData, setFormData\] = useState({
street: "",
number: "",
city: "",
state: "",
neighborhood: "",
zipCode: "",
} as FormData);

const router = useRouter();

const totalTabs = 2;

const disableUpload =
!file ||
!formData.street ||
!formData.number ||
!formData.city ||
!formData.state ||
isUploading;

function handleSelectFile(e: ChangeEvent\<HTMLInputElement\>) {
const files = e.target.files;

    if (!files || files.length != 1) return;
    
    if ((files.item(0)?.size as number) > FILE_SIZE_LIMIT) {
      alert("Você só pode enviar arquivos de até 5 MB");
      return;
    }
    
    setFile(files.item(0));
    fetchExcelData(files.item(0), setHeaders);

}

useEffect(() =\> {
if (user?.points === 0) {
router.push("/credits");
}
}, \[user\]);

const clearInput = () =\> {
if (isUploading) {
errorToast(
"Não é possível enviar outro arquivo enquanto um está sendo enviado"
);
}
setFile(null);
};

const toggleCyclicalRoute = (e: ChangeEvent\<HTMLInputElement\>) =\> {
const checked = e.target.checked;
setCyclicalRoute(checked);
};

const handleSubmit = async (e: FormEvent) =\> {
e.preventDefault();

    if (disableUpload) return;
    
    if (checkIfDuplicated(formData)) {
      errorToast("Colunas duplicadas!");
      return;
    }
    
    promiseToast(
      "Realizando o upload...",
      async () => {
        try {
          await uploadService.uploadDynamicColumns(
            file,
            formData.street,
            formData.number,
            formData.city,
            formData.state,
            roundTrip,
            formData.neighborhood,
            formData.zipCode
          );
          router.push("/history");
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
          if (isAxiosError(error)) {
            throw new Error(error.response?.data.error);
          }
    
          if (isError(error)) {
            throw new Error(error.message);
          }
    
          throw new Error("Erro ao tentar enviar o formulário");
        }
      },
      "Upload realizado com sucesso"
    );

};

const handleInputChange = (e: ChangeEvent\<HTMLInputElement\>): void =\> {
let { name, value } = e.target;

    setFormData({
      ...formData,
      [name]: value,
    });

};

const handleInputClick = (inputName: string) =\> {
setActiveInput(inputName);
setShowDropdown(true);
};

const handleInputBlur = () =\> {
setShowDropdown(false);
};

const moveToNext = () =\> {
setActiveItem((prev) =\> (prev + 1) % totalTabs);
};

const moveToPrevious = () =\> {
setActiveItem((prev) =\> (prev - 1 + totalTabs) % totalTabs);
};

const clearSelectedInput = () =\> {
setSelectedAddress(null);
};

return (
\<Card className={styles\["upload-card"\]}\>
\<Image
src={`${BASE_IMAGE_PATH}/geoportal-logo.png`}
alt="geoportal_logo"
width={200}
height={50}
/\>
\<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}\>
\<Carousel activeItem={activeItem} setActiveItem={setActiveItem}\>
\<CarouselSlide position={0}\>
\<div className={styles\["container"\]}\>
\<div className={styles\["card-title"\]}\>
<h1>Roteirização</h1>
\<IoIosArrowForward
className={styles\["tab-icon"\]}
onClick={() =\> {
moveToNext();
}}
/\>
\</div\>
<p>Selecione uma tabela com endereços (Excel)</p>
\<div\>
\<label htmlFor="upload" className={styles\["label"\]}\>
\<span\>Selecionar arquivo\</span\>
\<FaFileUpload className={styles\["upload-icon"\]} /\>
\</label\>
\</div\>
\<input
                onChange={handleSelectFile}
                type="file"
                name="upload"
                id="upload"
                accept=".xls, .xlsx"
              /\>
\<div className={styles\["uploaded-file"\]}\>
{file ? (
\<div\>
\<div\>
\<SiMicrosoftexcel className={styles\["upload-icon"\]} /\>
\<span\>
{file.name} - {formatFileSize(file.size)}
\</span\>
\</div\>
\<MdOutlineClose
className={styles\["button-icon"\]}
onClick={clearInput}
/\>
\</div\>
) : (
\<span\>Nenhum arquivo selecionado\</span\>
)}
\</div\>
\<SelectAddress setSelectedAddress={setSelectedAddress} /\>
\<div className={styles\["uploaded-address"\]}\>
{selectedAddress ? (
\<div className={styles\["uploaded-address-container"\]}\>
\<span\>
{selectedAddress?.name}, {selectedAddress?.nearNumber} -{" "}
{selectedAddress?.city}, {selectedAddress?.state}
\</span\>
\<MdOutlineClose
className={styles\["button-icon"\]}
onClick={() =\> clearSelectedInput()}
/\>
\</div\>
) : (
\<span\>Nenhum endereço selecionado\</span\>
)}
\</div\>
\<button
className={styles\["select-fields"\]}
onClick={() =\> moveToNext()}
type="button"
\\>
Selecione os campos da planilha
\</button\>
\</div\>
\</CarouselSlide\>
\<CarouselSlide position={1}\>
\<div className={`${styles["container"]} ${styles["second"]}`}\>
\<div className={styles\["card-title"\]}\>
<h1>Campos da planilha</h1>
\<IoIosArrowBack
className={styles\["tab-icon"\]}
onClick={moveToPrevious}
/\>
\</div\>
\<div className={styles\["form-content"\]}\>
\<div\>
\<label htmlFor="street"\>Rua (1° Coluna)\</label\>
\<input
id="street"
type="text"
required
onChange={handleInputChange}
onClick={() =\> handleInputClick("street")}
onBlur={handleInputBlur}
name="street"
value={formData.street}
placeholder="Escreva o nome da sua coluna"
/\>
\<SpreadSheetOptions
headers={headers}
disabled={!showDropdown || activeInput != "street"}
inputName="street"
setFormData={setFormData}
/\>
\</div\>
\<label htmlFor="number"\>Número (2° Coluna)\</label\>
\<input
id="number"
type="text"
required
onChange={handleInputChange}
onClick={() =\> handleInputClick("number")}
onBlur={handleInputBlur}
value={formData.number}
name="number"
placeholder="Escreva o nome da sua coluna"
/\>
\<SpreadSheetOptions
headers={headers}
disabled={!showDropdown || activeInput != "number"}
inputName="number"
setFormData={setFormData}
/\>
\<div\>
\<label htmlFor="city"\>Cidade (3° Coluna)\</label\>
\<input
id="city"
type="text"
required
onChange={handleInputChange}
onClick={() =\> handleInputClick("city")}
onBlur={handleInputBlur}
name="city"
value={formData.city}
placeholder="Escreva o nome da sua coluna"
/\>
\<SpreadSheetOptions
headers={headers}
disabled={!showDropdown || activeInput != "city"}
inputName="city"
setFormData={setFormData}
/\>
\</div\>
\<div\>
\<label htmlFor="state"\>Estado (4° Coluna)\</label\>
\<input
type="text"
required
onChange={handleInputChange}
onClick={() =\> handleInputClick("state")}
onBlur={handleInputBlur}
name="state"
value={formData.state}
placeholder="Escreva o nome da sua coluna"
/\>
\<SpreadSheetOptions
headers={headers}
disabled={!showDropdown || activeInput != "state"}
inputName="state"
setFormData={setFormData}
/\>
\</div\>
\<div\>
\<label htmlFor="neighborhood"\>Bairro (5° Coluna)\</label\>
\<input
id="neighborhood"
type="text"
onChange={handleInputChange}
onClick={() =\> handleInputClick("neighborhood")}
onBlur={handleInputBlur}
value={formData.neighborhood}
name="neighborhood"
placeholder="Escreva o nome da sua coluna"
/\>
\<SpreadSheetOptions
headers={headers}
disabled={!showDropdown || activeInput != "neighborhood"}
inputName="neighborhood"
setFormData={setFormData}
/\>
\</div\>
\<div\>
\<label htmlFor="zipcode"\>Cep (6° Coluna)\</label\>
\<input
id="zipcode"
type="text"
list="headers"
onChange={handleInputChange}
onClick={() =\> handleInputClick("zipCode")}
onBlur={handleInputBlur}
name="zipCode"
value={formData.zipCode}
placeholder="Escreva o nome da sua coluna"
/\>
\<SpreadSheetOptions
headers={headers}
disabled={!showDropdown || activeInput != "zipCode"}
inputName="zipCode"
setFormData={setFormData}
/\>
\</div\>
\</div\>
\</div\>
\</CarouselSlide\>
\</Carousel\>
\<div className={styles\["form-controls"\]}\>
\<div className={styles\["checkbox-container"\]}\>
\<label htmlFor="checkbox" className={styles\["checkbox-label"\]}\>
Viagem de ida e volta
\</label\>
\<input
              id="checkbox"
              type="checkbox"
              checked={roundTrip}
              onChange={toggleCyclicalRoute}
            /\>
\</div\>
\<button className={styles\["upload-button"\]} disabled={disableUpload}\>
\<span\>Enviar\</span\>
\<FaCloudUploadAlt className={styles\["upload-icon"\]} /\>
\</button\>
\</div\>
\</form\>
\</Card\>
);
}

export default UploadCard;

import { Dispatch, SetStateAction } from "react";
import styles from "./SpreadSheetOptions.module.css";
import { FormData } from "./UploadCard";

type SpreadSheetOptionsProps = {
headers: string\[\];
disabled: boolean;
inputName: string;
setFormData: Dispatch\<SetStateAction\<FormData\>\>;
};

const SpreadSheetOptions = ({
headers,
disabled,
inputName,
setFormData,
}: SpreadSheetOptionsProps) =\> {
const active = !disabled && headers.length \> 0;

function handleAddressSelect(option: string): void {
console.log(event)
console.log('teste')
console.log(option);
console.log('teste')

    if (inputName == "street")
      setFormData((prev) => ({
        ...prev,
        street: option,
      }));
    
    if (inputName == "number")
      setFormData((prev) => ({
        ...prev,
        number: option,
      }));
    
    if (inputName == "city")
      setFormData((prev) => ({
        ...prev,
        city: option,
      }));
    
    if (inputName == "state")
      setFormData((prev) => ({
        ...prev,
        state: option,
      }));
    
    if (inputName == "neighborhood")
      setFormData((prev) => ({
        ...prev,
        neighborhood: option,
      }));
    
    if (inputName == "zipCode")
      setFormData((prev) => ({
        ...prev,
        zipCode: option,
      }));

}

return (
\<div className={`${styles["dropdown"]}`}\>
{active && (
\<ul className={`${styles["dropdown-menu"]} ${styles["active"]}`}\>
{headers.map((address) =\> {
return (
\<li
key={address + inputName}
className={styles\["address"\]}
onClick={() =\> handleAddressSelect(address)}
\\>
\<div className={`${styles["content"]}`}\>
<a href="#">{address}</a>
\</div\>
</li>
);
})}
</ul>
)}
\</div\>
);
};

export default SpreadSheetOptions;

This is my css for the SpreadSheetComponent
.dropdown {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
opacity: 100%;
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
}

.dropdown span {
font-size: x-large;
font-weight: 700;
color: var(--primary-color);
}

.dropdown-menu {
position: absolute;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
list-style: none;
background-color: white;
height: 100px;
width: 90%;
border: 1px solid var(--font-medium);
overflow-y: auto;
border-radius: 0.25rem;
transform: translateY(-10px);
opacity: 0;
transition:
transform 300ms ease-out,
opacity 300ms ease-out;
z-index: -1;
}

.dropdown-menu.active {
transform: translateY(0);
opacity: 1;
z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-menu .address {
width: 100%;
font-size: 0.85rem;
color: var(--primary-color);
background-color: white;
padding: 0.25rem 1rem;

transition:
background 200ms ease-in,
color 200ms ease-in;
}

.dropdown-menu .address h2 {
font-weight: 700;
font-size: medium;
color: var(--primary-color);
border: none;
}

.dropdown-menu .address h2:hover {
color: white;
}

.dropdown-menu .content {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: space-between;
}

.dropdown-menu .address a {
outline: none;
display: inline-block;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
text-decoration: none;
background-color: inherit;
color: inherit;
}

.dropdown-menu li a {
display: block;
padding: 0.25rem;
color: var(--primary-color);
margin: 0.1em 0;
text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown-menu .address:hover {
background-color: var(--primary-color);
color: white;
cursor: pointer;
}

.content a {
font-size: 0.85rem;
}

I tried debugging with console logs, I checked the state behaviour, checked the css stylying. I really don't have any idea what could cause this problem.

Are there issue with every click handler?  Or only specific ones?

Welcome to StackOverflow. Since there's too much code, please consider create a minimal reproducible example

In the code you've provided there are all sorts of improper \ characters. Here's one example
onClick={() =\> handleAddressSelect(address)}

proper syntax is
onClick={() => handleAddressSelect(address)}


These slashs are related to StackOverFlow format. They do not exist in the code.

have you tried simplifying your component to just the basics and updating a very basic state?

The problem was solved. It was a matter of letting the style be controlled by the parent component. For some reason, I was not able to use expression like {condition && ...} to render my component. Very strange behaviour, but after I controlled the style by the parent component everything worked fine.
